# Alert appearing once in Javascript

Tags: javascript, alert

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script language = "JavaScript">
function calculate()
{
if (document.eMarkForm.option.value=="1" )
{
    window.alert("Thanks for using E-Marks");
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="eMarkForm">
<select name="option">
<option value="1">First Time User</option>
<option value="2">Frequent Flier</option>
<option value="3">Buying a Degree</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Go for It" onclick="calculate();aloop()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a form which the user can fill out and for one of the sections they can choose either one of these options. However, I want an alert to pop up only once when the first time "First Time User" has been submitted with the form.

Answer (score 0):

Add a check condition..

```
var check = false;

function calculate() {
    if (!check) {
        if (document.eMarkForm.option.value == "1") {
            window.alert("Thanks for using E-Marks");
        }
    }
    check = true;
}​
```